# ownCloud API for C# or VB.NET

Tags: c#, api, owncloud

I am trying to connect my C# application to ownCloud so that I can:

- authenticate with ownCloud
- upload files to ownCloud
- view the files uploaded to ownCloud
- open the files uploaded to ownCloud
- and manage users and groups from C# from the C# application

Could someone recommend an API to do these tasks in C# or VB.NET?

Comment: Do you need public domain? LGPL-like? GPL-like? Proprietary?

Comment: Any api would be ok as long as it works with c# or vb.net. tks!

Answer (score 2):

ownCloud provides a webdav interface. So you could use this small library in C# that provides most functions you need: https://github.com/kvdb/WebDAVClient

Only thing that is missing: managing users and groups.

I was reading about this, and found this thread:
http://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=19412
It seems that the Provisioning API was removed from ownCloud community edition, as mentioned in the thread.

It seems it is better to use LDAP for user and group management, and connect ownCloud and your c# application to LDAP.