# What's the best approach for archiving/storing many files to easily access them later?

Tags: file-management, document-management, cloud-storage, archiving, document-indexing

I'm looking for a way to efficiently store and archive my files, in a way that anyone could be able to find and access whatever files he would have been looking for at any time without any problems, like how websites like Wikipedia stores and lists articles, etc.

I have tons of different files scattered around various storage devices, each of them stored in multiple folders one inside another like a maze of folders and subfolders or a needle in a haystack, which make the process of finding a specific file extra difficult and time-consuming, even by using the Windows search function which takes sometimes forever to find a file, often end up lost and confused. The files are from many different file extensions and types, e.g. photos, videos, text files, RAR, ZIP, etc.

My idea is to have something mimic the Google or other organized and engineered websites. Something that has artificial intelligence and would sort the files in various methods.

I think my problem and idea is common, otherwise, how professional computer users which their job is to work with files and the internet could access a certain file in their personal storage which could be possibly tens of terabytes in size? I think the approach should be similar to those used by large and famous companies and project managers etc.

Any software or method or even hardware recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: What OS(es) must be supported? Reading between the lines, you're working on Windows, so I guess that's the target? Also, what's your price margin in case it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: Do desktop search engines look useful? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines#Desktop_search_engines

Comment: How do you expect a computer to categorize your files automatically? No offence, if you had 100 invoice jpg's and 100 family photos, can a program distinguish them? Also searching for *.jpg *.png... then cut / paste to a folder would work fine. Am I wrong?

Comment: And I don't think a system like Wikipedia could be done automatically or using a software. There's o lot of labour.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should consider [Owncloud](https://owncloud.org/)? Here is a quote from it:

> Access your data from all your devices, on an open platform you can extend and modify.

The way I often introduce OwnCloud to somebody new to it is like "*Think of it as your 'private' version of Dropbox, somewhere in the cloud. Where 'you' set the terms and conditions for anybody you authorize to use it ... And free of charge, except of course the cost to implement and run it on 'your' server. Did I mention syncing with phones, tables, etc, instead of using iCloud (and its terms and conditions ...)?*".

There are also some [questions about Owncloud around here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=owncloud%20is%3Aq) that may be worth exploring ...

Comment: Thanks. Looks great but I'm more considering a system or method of managing lots of files, that's my main problem. I can't easily access my old files, it's like digging into the ground for finding a treasure, not an easy task.

Comment: I added the [tag:owncloud] tag to [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3975/60) some time ago, but the tag got deleted because it had no tag wiki / not enough questions. As far as I can see, no other question should have it. I’ll add it again now.

Comment: @unor : merci for re-adding the owncloud tag ... looking at the (24) search results using the link in my answer, I think there are a few other questions that should be retagged (= add that owncloud tag). Do you want me to "suggest an edit" for those that I think make sense (hoping I don't get banned from suggesting them if I make a mistake ...). Note: I'm planning on submitting a wiki suggestion soon also ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: On this site, we decided to use product tags only for questions that look for software that *must* be compatible with this product. So questions asking for ownCloud alternatives or questions where ownCloud would be a good answer should not be tagged with it. -- Maybe I missed a question, but the one with the API was the only one I found where ownCloud support was required.

Comment: I remember there was a software which could categorize files and it had an animal on its logo as far as I remember. Any guesses?